# Removing multiple named list components in within()

Tags: r, list, null, with-statement, named

I am trying to remove a named component from a list, using `within` and `rm`. This works for a single component, but not for two or more. I am completely befuddled.

For example - this works

```
aa = list(a = 1:3, b = 2:5, cc = 1:5)
within(aa, {rm(a)})
```

the output from `within` will have just the non-removed components.

However, this does not:

```
aa = list(a = 1:3, b = 2:5, cc = 1:5)
within(aa, {rm(a); rm(b)})
```

Neither does this:

```
within(aa, {rm(a, b)})
```

The output from `within` will have all the components, with the ones I am trying to remove, set to `NULL`. Why?

Comment: Well, yes. But I am trying to do it inside within

Comment: This is weird behaviour! you can delete one, but after that they stay on as NULL - even if there are more than 3 columns. Works similarly with `within(aa, {"b"<-NULL; "a"<-NULL})`

Answer (score 4):

First, note the following behavior:

```
> aa = list(a = 1:3, b = 2:5, cc = 1:5)
>
> aa[c('a', 'b')] <- NULL
>
> aa
# $cc
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5

> aa = list(a = 1:3, b = 2:5, cc = 1:5)
>
> aa[c('a', 'b')] <- list(NULL, NULL)
>
> aa
# $a
# NULL
#
# $b
# NULL
#
# $cc
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Now let's look at the code for `within.list`:

```
within.list <- function (data, expr, ...) 
{
    parent <- parent.frame()
    e <- evalq(environment(), data, parent)
    eval(substitute(expr), e)
    l <- as.list(e)
    l <- l[!sapply(l, is.null)]
    nD <- length(del <- setdiff(names(data), (nl <- names(l))))
    data[nl] <- l
    if (nD) 
        data[del] <- if (nD == 1) NULL else vector("list", nD)
    data
}
```

Look in particular at the second to last line of the function. If the number of deleted items in the list is greater than one, the function is essentially calling `aa[c('a', 'b')] <- list(NULL, NULL)`, because `vector("list", 2)` creates a two item list where each item is `NULL`. We can create our own version of `within` where we remove the `else` statement from the second to last line of the function:

```
mywithin <- function (data, expr, ...) 
{
    parent <- parent.frame()
    e <- evalq(environment(), data, parent)
    eval(substitute(expr), e)
    l <- as.list(e)
    l <- l[!sapply(l, is.null)]
    nD <- length(del <- setdiff(names(data), (nl <- names(l))))
    data[nl] <- l
    if (nD) data[del] <- NULL
    data
}
```

Now let's test it:

```
> aa = list(a = 1:3, b = 2:5, cc = 1:5)
>
> mywithin(aa, rm(a, b))
# $cc
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Now it works as expected!

Comment: Ah, yes. Should have thought to look at the source. Much appreciate!

Comment: This is very neat, but why do you need to remove the else clause from `within.list`? and assuming it's a bug, please file an R bug on `base::within`